# How to click the corner most in pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I wish to know how to click the corner most in the identified image in pyautogui.

**Sample header image:**

[image]

I am able to identify the above image but not sure how to click the right corner most whic is a button with **caption 'C'.**

I am aware of how to click the center but did not find a solution yet to click on other place in a identified image.

Could someone help please?

Comment: Why not isolate the image of the button area and find it['s center?

Comment: @itprorh66: I am unable to crop the specific very small portion via snipper tool. I did try alternative but it is not as good as snipper tool.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the caption button stays constant in relation to the location of the image above

```
#experiment to find the correct num

image_coords = list(pyautogui.locateOnScreen()

image_coords[0] += num

pyautogui.moveto(image_coords)
```